# Can I/ Should I free pointer returned by strtok

Tags: c, string, pointers, memory-management, free

So I am dynamically creating an array of strings. I am then assigning each element in that array a pointer returned by calling strtok. At the end of my process when I need to redo everything I have been trying to free the pointers in the elements of said array, but I keep getting an error stating

`*** glibc detected *** ./prgm: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fff600d98`

Also, would it make sense to free inputStr at the end of the loop?

Where is my logical "not really logical at all" thinking wrong.. 
e.g code

```
   char** argvNew = (char**)calloc(33,sizeof(char*));
   char inputStr[128];  
   do{    
        scanf("%127[^\n]%*c", inputStr);
        token = strtok(inputStr, delim);

        /* Add tokens to array*/
        varNum= 0;
        for(i = 0; token != NULL; i++){
            varNum++;
            argvNew[i] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        }
        argvNew[i] = NULL;

       //Free argvNew 
        for(i = 0; i < varNum;i++){
            printf("Deleting %i, %s\n",i,argvNew[i]);
            free(argvNew[i]);
        }
  while(1);
```

Comment: i apologize for my low tier c, as I have been programming too much in java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you should not free it. It's returning a pointer to a character in `inputStr` (or `NULL` when it reaches the end). It's not allocating any new memory, so there's nothing to free.

If `inputStr` is dynamically allocated, you should free it when you're done with it.

Comment: so i won't get a memory leak on the next iteration of my loop?

Comment: How can you get a memory leak if you're not allocating anything?

Comment: how can I be so dumb.. just happens

Comment: @Javant don't blame yourself. I think this was a nice question, and most people coming from [tag:java] has (or should) have this kind of questions! That's I upvoted you!

Answer (score 4):

No, since it's not allocating new memory.

Quoting the [ref of strtok()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/):

> **Return Value**
>
> If a token is found, *a pointer to the beginning of the token*. Otherwise, a null pointer. A null pointer is always
>   returned when the end of the string (i.e., a null character) is
>   reached in the string being scanned.

The example of the ref, doesn't free what `strtok()` returns, which confirms:

```
/* strtok example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

You see the returned pointer of `strtok()` will be used just to access the memory already created by your program (regardless of whether this was created dynamically or not; here it is created statically). It won't be assigned newly created memory, thus you shouldn't free it.

---

In general, this is what you should have in mind:

**Call `free()` as many times as you call `malloc()`.**

Comment: But sometimes functions call `malloc()` internally. For instance, `strdup()`.

Comment: Yet another non standard [tag:c] function BarmaR, but yes you are right in general. However the question is about `strtok()`. I hope I answered your worry. Let's try to keep it reasonable for a beginner in [tag:c] please! :)

Answer (score -1):

You only allocated the `argvNew` array. And that's the only thing you should be deallocating.

You did not allocate what the pointers in `argvNew` are pointing to, so you are not going to `free()` them.