# Function returns char**s, running the function twice causes the return value to differ

Tags: c, pointers, strtok

Description of what my function attempts to do

My function gets a string for example "Ab +  abc EF++aG hi  jkL" and turns it into ["abc", "hi"]

In addition, the function only takes into account letters and the letters all have to be lowercase.

The problem is that

```
char* str1 = "Ab +  abc EF++aG hi  jkL";
char* str2 = "This is a very famous quote";

char** tokens1 = get_tokens(str1); 
printf("%s", tokens1[0]);            <----- prints out "abc" correct output
char** tokens2 = get_tokens(str2);
printf("%s", tokens1[0]);            <----- prints out "s" incorrect output
```

get_tokens function (Returns the 2d array)

```
char** get_tokens(const char* str) {
  // implement me
  int num_tokens = count_tokens(str); 

  char delim[] = " ";
  int str_length = strlen(str);
  char* new_str = malloc(str_length); 
  strcpy(new_str, str); 

  char* ptr = strtok(new_str, delim);
  int index = 0;

  char** array_2d = malloc(sizeof(char*) *num_tokens);

  while (ptr != NULL){
    if (check_string(ptr) == 0){

      array_2d[index] = ptr; 
      index++;
    }

    ptr = strtok(NULL, delim); 
  } 

  free(new_str); 
  new_str = NULL; 

  free(ptr);
  ptr = NULL; 

  return array_2d;
}
```

count_tokens function (returns the number of valid strings)

for example count_tokens("AB + abc EF++aG hi jkL") returns 2 because only "abc" and "hi" are valid

```
int count_tokens(const char* str) {
  // implement me
  //Seperate string using strtok

  char delim[] = " ";
  int str_length = strlen(str);
  char* new_str = malloc(str_length); 
  strcpy(new_str, str); 

  char* ptr = strtok(new_str, delim); 

  int counter = 0; 

  while (ptr != NULL){
    if (check_string(ptr) == 0){
      counter++;
    }

    ptr = strtok(NULL, delim); 
  }
  free(new_str);     
  return counter;
}
```

Lastly check_string() checks if a string is valid

For example check_string("Ab") is invalid because there is a A inside.

using strtok to split "Ab + abc EF++aG hi jkL" into separate parts

```
int check_string(char* str){ 
  // 0 = false 
  // 1 = true
  int invalid_chars = 0; 

   for (int i = 0; i<strlen(str); i++){
     int char_int_val = (int) str[i];
     if (!((char_int_val >= 97 && char_int_val <= 122))){
        invalid_chars = 1; 
    }
   }

  return invalid_chars;  
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you for reading.

If you have any questions about how the code works please ask me. Also I'm new to stackoverflow, please tell me if I have to change something.

Comment: For starters, `char* new_str = malloc(str_length); strcpy(new_str, str);` is incorrect. You forgot to do +1 for the NUL terminator, that is `malloc(str_length+1)`. When `strcpy` writes the string, the NUL terminator it adds overflows `new_str` by one, invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: `free(ptr);` is incorrect, you [don't free the returned pointer from `strtok`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39282669/can-i-should-i-free-pointer-returned-by-strtok)

Comment: Just a few "better practice" suggestions: 1) You can `#include <stdbool.h>` and use a `bool` type for true and false, rather than 0 and 1 `int`s. 2) It's better to use the character rather than magic numbers, eg `(char_int_val >= 'a' && char_int_val <= 'z')`. 3) You can `break` from the `for` loop as soon as you find the first invalid char, nothing is gained by continuing to search.

Comment: I have updated the code using malloc(str_length+1) but I'm still getting the same wrong outputs.

Comment: I fixed it by allocating memory to my ptr

Comment: Then you just got "lucky" this time, and it may very well fail again down the road (on a different system, with different compiler flags, when your TA compiles and grades it, etc). If you do `ptr = malloc(...)` then `ptr = strtok(...)`, all you've done is create a memory leak. You've lost the pointer to the `malloc`ed memory, so you can never free it, and this has no bearing on how `strtok` operates or performs. `strtok` returns a pointer to offset of already-allocated memory. `malloc`ing some before that is entirely inconsequential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems in your code.  First I'll repeat what I've said in the comments:

- Not allocating enough space for the string copies.  `strlen` does *not* include the NUL terminator in its length, so when you do

```c
char* new_str = malloc(str_length); 
strcpy(new_str, str);
```

`new_str` overflows by 1 when `strcpy` adds the `'\0'`, invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  You need to allocate one extra:

```c
char* new_str = malloc(str_length + 1); 
strcpy(new_str, str);
```

- You should not [`free`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/free) any pointer returned from [`strtok`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtok.3.html).  You only `free` memory that's been dynamically allocated using `malloc` and friends.  `strtok` does no such thing, so it's [incorrect to `free` the pointer it returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39282669/can-i-should-i-free-pointer-returned-by-strtok).  Doing so also invokes UB.

Your final problem is because of this:

```c
// copy str to new_str, that's correct because strtok
// will manipulate the string you pass into it
strcpy(new_str, str);  
// get the first token and allocate size for the number of tokens,
// so far so good (but you should check that malloc succeeded)
char* ptr = strtok(new_str, delim);
char** array_2d = malloc(sizeof(char*) *num_tokens);

while (ptr != NULL){
    if (check_string(ptr) == 0){
      // whoops, this is where the trouble starts ...
      array_2d[index] = ptr; 
      index++;
    }
    // get the next token, this is correct
    ptr = strtok(NULL, delim); 
  } 
  // ... because you free new_str
  free(new_str);
```

`ptr` is a pointer to some token in `new_str`.  As soon as you `free(new_str)`, Any pointer pointing to that now-deallocated memory is invalid.  You've loaded up `array_2d` with pointers to memory that's no longer allocated.  Trying to access those locations again invokes undefined behavior.  There's two ways I can think of off the top to solve this:

1. Instead of saving pointers that are offsets to `new_str`, find the same tokens in `str` (the string from `main`) and point to those instead.  Since those are defined in `main`, they will exist for as long as the program exists.
2. Allocate some more memory, and `strcpy` the token into `array_2d[index]`.  I'll demonstrate this below:

```c
while (ptr != NULL){
    if (check_string(ptr) == false)
    {
      // allocate (enough) memory for the pointer at index
      array_2d[index] = malloc(strlen(ptr) + 1);
      // you should _always_ check that malloc succeeds
      if (array_2d[index] != NULL)
      {
          // _copy_ the string pointed to by ptr into our new space rather
          // than simply assigning the pointer
          strcpy(array_2d[index], ptr);
      }
      else { /* handle no mem error how you want */ }
      index++;
    }

    ptr = strtok(NULL, delim); 
}

// now we can safely free new_str without invalidating anything in array_2d
free(new_str);
```

I have a working [demonstration here](https://godbolt.org/z/r1eq9jP3P).  Note some other changes in the demo:

- `#include <stdbool.h>` and used that instead of 0 and 1 `int`s.
- Changed your `get_tokens` function a bit to "return" the number of tokens.  This is useful in `main` for printing them out.
- Replaced the ASCII magic numbers with their characters.
- Removed the useless `freedPointer = NULL` lines.
- Changed your `int`s to `size_t` types for everything involving a size.

One final note, while this is a valid implementation, it's probably doing a bit more work than it needs to.  Rather than counting the number of tokens in a first pass, then retrieving them in a second pass, you can surely do everything you want in a single pass, but I'll leave that as an exercise to you if you're so inclined.

Comment: thank you this was exactly the problem, I wish I can upvote you but I don't have enough points

Comment: @sam no worries, happy to help!